# Python Dictionary: I would like to combine multiple lists into a single dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have 3 lists:

- Task names
- Start times
- End times

I'm using

```
dict(zip(starting_tasks,zip(starting_time,end_time)))
```

and getting the output as:

```
{'Task1': ('time1', 'time2'), 'Task2': ('time3', 'time4')}
```

I would like to have the output as follows:

```
mydict = 
{
​​​​​​​​'Task1': {​​​​​​​'start_time': 'time1', 'end_time': 'time2'}​​​​​​​, 
'Task2': {​​​​​​​​'start_time': 'time3', 'end_time': 'time4'}
...
'TaskN': {​​​​​​​​'start_time': 'timeX', 'end_time': 'timeY'}
​​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​​
```

The keywords "start_time" and "end_time" are not present in any list. They are simply the strings I want to use as the key.

Is there any way I can combine these lists or dictionaries to get the above? In the end, I need it in this format: dict{key: dict{key:value, key:value},...}

Comment: I only see 3 lists

Comment: I have updated the question. I have given the format I'm getting it in currently and also the format I'd prefer

Comment: please add example values for your 3 lists, that way your code is reproducible

Answer (score 1):

You can do this thanks to dict comprehension. By the way, your *three* lists must be all equal size, else `zip` will stop with the shortest list.

```py
>>> l1, l2, l3 = ["task1", "task2"], ["start1_value", "start2_value"], ["end1_value", "end2_value"]
>>> d = {task: {"start_time": start, "end_time": end} for (task, start, end) in zip(l1, l2, l3)}
>>> d
{'task1': {'start_time': 'start1_value', 'end_time': 'end1_value'}, 'task2': {'start_time': 'start2_value', 'end_time': 'end2_value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

All three lists have to be of the same length to make this work.
If you don't want to use zip then the following example will work for you.

```
tasknames = ['task1', 'task2']
start_time = ['time1', 'time2']
end_time = ['time3', 'time4']

dict = {}
for i in range(len(tasknames)):
     dict[tasknames[i]] = {'start_time':start_time[i], 'end_time': end_time[i]}

print(dict)
```

output:

```
{
    'task1': {'start_time': 'time1', 'end_time': 'time3'},
    'task2': {'start_time': 'time2', 'end_time': 'time4'}
}
```